# How to plot Magnitude response focusing on passband ripple

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have been asked to plot the magnitude response of an impulse using butterworth filter.
I did that already, [b,a] = butter(n, Wn, 'low') & freqz(b, a)

However, I have also been asked to output the magnitude response focusing on the passband ripple

> Plot the magnitude response (in dB) from ω = 0 to ω = π using freqz.
>   Plot a detail of the magnitude response, focusing on the passband
>   ripple (linear scale)

What are the steps to do this in matlab? is there a command where I can output this without using the fdatool? I do not know what to do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you just need to zoom in on the area of interest. I should be just a matter of plotting the data again and changing the X and Y axes limits to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question correctly, I think it is pretty easy.. You can do it by:

```
fvtool(Hd)
```

You can find more info here: http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fdesign.lowpass.html

Hope it helps, and good luck with your homework!

Comment: This is not a homework for school, I do this as a hobby! So since you know about this very well, can you tell me how to plot it using subplot()?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I am on holidays these days, so I am not using the computer too much.

I can't think on a direct way to do what you want, but here is a workaround:

`h=fvtool(Hd);
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children'); dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children');
xdata = get(dataObjs{6}, 'XData'); ydata = get(dataObjs{6}, 'YData');

figure
plot(xdata{2},ydata{2},xdata{1},ydata{1},'r:');
axis([xs,xf,ys,yf])`

... where `xs` and `xf` represent the start and finish in the X axis, and the `ys` and `yf` the same in Y axes. (e.g: [0,22,-600,10])

By the way, nice hobby!!